# Flutter: Using moor generated model json factory in chopper converter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-moor, chopper

I'm using moor as a local storage in my Flutter app, I created the tables, and moor generated the models for me, with a fromJson factory and a toJson method. example:

```
class Addresse extends DataClass implements Insertable<Addresse> {
  final int id;
  final String street1;
  final String street2;
  final String city;
  final String zip;
  final String country;
  final String state;
  //constructor generated here
  // fromData method here
  // toColumns method here
  // toCompanion method here

  factory Addresse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json,
      {ValueSerializer serializer}) {
    serializer ??= moorRuntimeOptions.defaultSerializer;
    return Addresse(
      id: serializer.fromJson<int>(json['id']),
      street1: serializer.fromJson<String>(json['street1']),
      street2: serializer.fromJson<String>(json['street2']),
      city: serializer.fromJson<String>(json['city']),
      zip: serializer.fromJson<String>(json['zip']),
      country: serializer.fromJson<String>(json['country']),
      state: serializer.fromJson<String>(json['state']),
    );
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson({ValueSerializer serializer}) {
    serializer ??= moorRuntimeOptions.defaultSerializer;
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'id': serializer.toJson<int>(id),
      'street1': serializer.toJson<String>(street1),
      'street2': serializer.toJson<String>(street2),
      'city': serializer.toJson<String>(city),
      'zip': serializer.toJson<String>(zip),
      'country': serializer.toJson<String>(country),
      'state': serializer.toJson<String>(state),
    };
  }

  //copyWith method here
  //toString method here

  //hash method here
  //equals method here
}
```

I'm using chopper to consume the APIs, and to create a chopper client, I need to tell it how to serialize and deserialize the request/response body.
Chopper offers this by setting the converter attr when creating a the Chopper Client:

```
ChopperClient(
  baseUrl: BASE_URL,
  services: services,
  interceptors: [
    HttpLoggingInterceptor(),
  ],
  converter: //add the converter here,
);
```

I want to make chopper use the fromJson and toJson generated by moor in my models, but I don't seem to find the right way to do that.
Any hints, guides are appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Comment: @Swisscheese nope, i have been told that it is a bad practice to relay on a generated code for another generated code.